# How to remove ListenerForSingleValueEvent?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `ValueEventListener` attached to a reference when opening my activity.

```
mServicesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(mServicesRefListener);
```

In the onPause method, I remove this listener

```
    public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    try{
        mServicesRef.removeEventListener(mServicesRefListener);
    }catch (Exception e){
        //Do nothing
    }

}
```

So upon leaving this activity, the listener should stop, but it doesn't.

Turning on airplane mode (cutting off internet access) and leaving from and going to this activity multiple times just stacks the event listeners, and removing them does not affect it. When turning off airplane mode, internet is back on, and the event listener fires multiple times (However many times I went back to the activity).

How can I stop this `ValueEventListener` for a single value event prematurely to keep it from firing multiple times when internet access is cut back on.

Comment: I recommend using `e.printStackTrace()`. It's likely an Exception is being thrown.

Comment: In addition to TheWanderer's great point, can you check if the `mServicesRef.removeEventListener(mServicesRefListener)` gets called at all?

Comment: I Log.d the Exception and removeEventListener. removeEventListener is in fact firing, but the error is not.

Comment: Usually addListenerForSingleValueEvent executes only once, and finishes when the data is fetched...

Comment: @JinsonPaul is correct. The only time `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` needs cancelling is if there is no network connection when you attach it, and the client doesn't have a local copy of the data (either because there was another active listener, or because it has a copy of the data on disk).